# Code to Check if time is at or before 2pm PHP

Tags: php

I have a code inside of a switch statement that is supposed to check if a time entered is at or before 2pm. If it is, it continues in the loop that it is in, if not, it skips the loop it's in (The switch statement is inside of a foreach loop). Here is my current code:

```
case '3370':
            $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO', $_SESSION["apptTime"]);
    $timestamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
    $time = date('H', $timestamp);
    if($time <= 14){
        $addonimage = 'https://mywebsite.com/image.png';
        break;

    }else{
        continue 2;
}
```

The code works for the most part, except when the time selected is for 2pm. I want it to create the `$addonimage` but instead, it goes to `continue 2`. How can I make it do this?

Update:

OK, So I did a little troubleshooting and I found out that the hour being passed is 15, where it should be 14. Here is a sample time being passed into the function: `2017-03-11T14:00:00-0800`. Does anyone know why it's passing 15 instead of 14?

Comment: You need to look at cron jobs. This is less to-do with PHP and more your operating system of choice. Basically you set a cron job which executes a PHP script via the command line. Without mention of your operating system you're unlikely to get s decent answer.

Comment: Hey @Doug grammatical correction. its `cron` not chron

Comment: @Doug Thank you for the answer, but I am not trying to run a script at a certain time. The script checks the time and based on the time entered, either includes `$addonimage` or doesn't. Though I do get the misunderstanding. I reworded the title to be more accurate to what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I always make that mistake because in my head it's short for chronological .

Comment: if in $time is 14 it's should work

Comment: @bxN5 I know, that is why I'm confused.

Comment: @EricBrown i mean u are sure that it's not work when time is 14 ?

Comment: What it return if you set `if($time < 15){`? Can you provide more data about `$time` returned values?

Comment: For sure `$timestamp` is going beyond 14 even if with one microsecond and it never gets `=` according to your description! Try to play around time format `('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO', $_SESSION["apptTime"])`

Comment: @wpcoder Yeah, it's reading 15 for some reason. I updated my question.

Comment: Check with this tool or similar you time stamp value to debug https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: one thing to note is that will yield the time based on the server location - so if you need the function to trigger based on the users location / timezone you would be better to use javascript to get the local time. if - if hte server is in the US and the ser is in Australia - server time will not be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

OK, I actually found something that works. Instead of using the `date` function, I just use the DateTime function. Here is what I have now:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO', $_SESSION["apptTime"]);
    $timestamp = $dateTime->format('H');
    if(intval($timestamp) <= 14){
```

This does exactly what I want it to do. Thank you everyone for your help!